# The World Wide Web or World's Wide Web which is correct

Tags: word-usage, possessives, modifiers

**World Wide Web** and **World's Wide Web**
which is grammatically correct.
which is proper. please kindly answer me.
i want to know the difference between them.

Comment: need to know major difference between them

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, it's the

> [World Wide Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web) - *a system of interlinked hypertext documents that are accessed via the Internet.*

The web refers to the internet and it is worldwide. The world does not have *possession* of it! No apostrophe please. Had 'Wide Web' being in possession of the world, we'd have said *World's Wide Web* but that's not the case.

We use apostrophe with the word 'World' in cases like 'World's largest tower'.

Comment: Yes - though technically both are *grammatically* correct, the first is actually a name for the internet.